# I get 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-recognition

Here is the code,

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16 
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input 
from keras.models import Model import numpy as np

class FeatureExtractor: def init(self): base_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet") self.model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer("fc1").output)
def extract(self, img):
    img = img.resize((224, 224)).convert("RGB")
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    feature = self.model.predict(x)[0]
    return feature / np.linalg.norm(feature)
```

I expected numpy.ndarray but i get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'

Following is the error stack

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ronte\OneDrive\Documents\Image Search Platfoem\static\offline.py", line 4, in <module>
    from featureextractor import FeatureExtractor
  File "C:\Users\Ronte\OneDrive\Documents\Image Search Platfoem\static\featureextractor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.preprocessing import image
  File "C:\Users\Ronte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras import __internal__
  File "C:\Users\Ronte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\__internal__\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras.__internal__ import backend
  File "C:\Users\Ronte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\__internal__\backend\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras.src.backend import _initialize_variables as initialize_variables
  File "C:\Users\Ronte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from keras.src import models
  File "C:\Users\Ronte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from keras.src.engine.functional import Functional
  File "C:\Users\Ronte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\functional.py", line 23, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'
```

Comment: This code does not mention `tensorflow.compat` at all, therefore the error must be happening somewhere else.  Please show us the full error traceback merssage, so we can see where the error actually occurs.

Comment: It's hard to read formatted code/errors in comments.  Please edit the question and put the error there.

Comment: Also, this can't be the full error, because it doesn't **start** with a line from your code.  It starts with a line from a library module.

Comment: @JohnGordon do you need more information

Comment: I don't know anything about tensorflow specifically, so I might not be of much more help.  One more question though -- is there a file named `tensorflow.py` (or `tensorflow.pyc`) in your project directory?

Comment: please run `pip list` and state the versions of keras and tensorflow

Comment: You are obviously using a version of Keras that is incompatible with your version of TensorFlow.